# Custom NPM module can't access the deployed version of the server from localhost

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, npm, module

[UPDATE]

I created an **NPM module** for my nodejs SDK.

My SDK is used to ease access to the server I develop.
In addition I develop a front-end, which imports the SDK and access to the server thru it.

**While developing:**

Summing up the architecture while developing in local:

```
http://localhost:3000/frontend (w/ imported npm sdk) --> http://localhost:5000/api
```

In localhost development, I import it and everything works well, the SDK consumes the localhost server I develop. (In devel mode, the module itself is npm link'ed).

**While testing:**

The SDK has a function that enables it to switch the infrastructure, so that it can be tested against previous version of the server deploy to production (or staging).

Summing up testing against production server after the sdk.switchToInfrastructure():

```
http://localhost:3000/frontend (w/ imported npm sdk) --> https://server.com/api
```

When I switch to something like the production server at https://server.com, all the requests issued from the SDK are blocked by the browser:

```
GET https://server.com/api net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I believe that the fact the front is still on HTTP causes the issue.

What to do to prevent this to occur? Or any tips to help in the process of testing one's NPM module against several deployed infrastructures.

**[UPDATE 2]**

Additional info: when I do not import my SDK via npm (I simply import the sdk from a local file), there is no issue at all, I can issue the request from localhost.

Comment: Looks like you don't have ssl certificate on the server, and your code tries to access it via https.

Comment: Alas, nope, the server has the ssl certificate installed and linked to the domain name. But, of course, localhost (that holds the front-end) is HTTP only. That's, for me, the source of the issue. I think my question is not clear enough and I'm going to make it better.

Answer (score -1):

The browser blocks [Cross Origin Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if your server not supports CORS.

This means that if your client (which runs on `localhost`) tries to fetch endpoint of `production.server.com` it will be blocked by default.

Read the article about CORS and how to enable it.

Comment: Actually, my server enables cors for the localhost:3000. As per my understanding, seeing no trace on the server, I think the browser blocks the request so hat tit is not actually issued.

Comment: Btw, one additional info I failed to tell is that if I do not import my SDK via npm but only import it from a local file, there is no issue at all, I can issue the request from localhost. I update the question with that info).